# Firebase Reset Password IOS App xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing an app that has a login page with a login button and main menu button. I've created everything and is working pretty well for the time being. I'm using Firebase as my backend database.

I wanted to create a 'forgot password' button which i already did and seems like its working but the only problem is it doesn't give me an alert when it sends the email, it just sends it, but i get the alert when i enter an email which is not in the user authentication. Below is my code for the forget password button:

```
    @IBAction func frgtpassTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: emailTextField.text!) { error in
        if self.emailTextField.text?.isEmpty==true{
            let resetFailedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Failed", message: "Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))", preferredStyle: .alert)
            resetFailedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(resetFailedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        if error != nil && self.emailTextField.text?.isEmpty==false{
            let resetEmailAlertSent = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Email Sent", message: "Reset email has been sent to your login email, please follow the instructions in the mail to reset your password", preferredStyle: .alert)
            resetEmailAlertSent.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(resetEmailAlertSent, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I accept if anyone downvotes this post but please if you do, comment below the reason. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: "which i already did" no you didnt, i did and you deleted the post with my answer. Reposted the question passing the solution as yours. Not cool.

Comment: Why would i delete your post? I don't have any previous post about this topic before this

Comment: You deleted the whole question of yours containing a post with my answer and you used my proposed solution in this question(which is the same as the initial one). I will not get into a debate, moderators can verify the truth...

Comment: I have no deleted question before that what are you talking about? If you answered something similar then not my fault, if you want i can give credit to you, you just had to ask. Plus, you can't delete a post that already has an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please this code

 Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: emailTextField.text!) { error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.emailTextField.text?.isEmpty==true || error != nil {
                    let resetFailedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Failed", message: "Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    resetFailedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(resetFailedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                if error == nil && self.emailTextField.text?.isEmpty==false{
                    let resetEmailAlertSent = UIAlertController(title: "Reset Email Sent", message: "Reset email has been sent to your login email, please follow the instructions in the mail to reset your password", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    resetEmailAlertSent.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(resetEmailAlertSent, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from your code, that you are passing the unWrapped value to the closure, so the textField must contains some value in it.

> THIS LINE IN YOUR CODE:  if self.emailTextField.text?.isEmpty==true {

will never be entered inside condition.
It should be updated to like:

```
@IBAction func frgtpassTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    //BEFORE SENDING DATA FOR AUTHENTICATION, CHECK FOR THE isEmpty CONDITIONS HERE
    Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: emailTextField.text!) { error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if error != nil {
                // YOUR ERROR CODE
            } else {
                //YOUR SUCCESS MESSAGE
            }
        }
    }
}
```